# How to load the react value after update using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to update the value, in the class component all we can do is `componentDidUpdate` and it works, 
this is the toggle for activation and deactivation of users

```
  {user.activated ? (
      <Button
          color="primary"
          onClick={toggleActive(user)}
          variant="contained">
              Activated
      </Button>
  ) : (
      <Button
          onClick={toggleActive(user)}
          variant="contained">
               Deactivated
      </Button>
 )}
```

and this is the function

```
const toggleActive = (user) => () => dispatch(updateUser({
    ...user,
    activated: !user.activated
}));
```

`//dispatch(updateUser()` this is using react-redux to update, well the value is updating but it's not changing the UI, I have to refresh to change the UI

Comment: How is user received by the component?

Comment: via props   ` const {
    className, users, match, ...rest
  } = props;`

Comment: can you create a reproducible demo on codesandbox?

Comment: show how you update redux state. you might be forgetting destructuring of your user object so that redux does not recognize the change.

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-meninsky-joyog?file=/src/App.js] @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: `  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch(updateUser);
    };
    fetchData();
  });   ` @Kerematam

Comment: Can't see your code in codesandbox

Comment: I mean your reducer code where you update your redux state.

Comment: try now @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: case TYPES.UPDATE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        updateSuccess: false,
        updating: true

      };

@Kerematam

Comment: This is not where you change user state. Please share your all reducer code in the answer.